# how to open multiple ulr in one webview (not once )

Tags: java, android, url, webview

$ second activity.java

```
package com.example.applincatio.buttonclick;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

ImageButton imageButton1;
    ImageButton imageButton2;
    ImageButton imageButton3;
    ImageButton imageButton4;
    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewmoddle);

imageButton1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MyButton1);

        imageButton2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MyButton2);
        imageButton3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MyButton3);    
        imageButton4=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MyButton4);    
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.moddlewebview);    
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebclient());        
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.kluniversity.in/");           
    }
    public class myWebclient extends WebViewClient {
                    @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);


}
```

$ main activity.java

```
package com.example.applincatio.buttonclick;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;
    ImageButton button3;
    ImageButton button4;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MyButton1);
        button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MyButton2);
        button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MyButton3);
        button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MyButton4);
        // Capture button clicks
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });



        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });



        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

I want to load multiple urls in one webview
for example 
if i click on image 1 then i want to open url 1
if i click on image 2 then i want to open url 2
like this each button should have different url

here I loaded only one URL, but I want to add three more URL by using if statements, but I cant change that.please anyone help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: Well, make `mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.kluniversity.in/");` depending on your condition ... Not clear where you have problems.

Comment: call `ClickListener` on buttons and set `mWebView.loadUrl("your url")` for each buttons. Thats it

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use listeners for ur imageViews.

```
imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("your url");
            }
        });
```

Comment: i added my main activity,java          ........... can you please check that and change tha code

Comment: the app gets stopped